# how to fix error CS0136

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scope

I have a script that gives me the error

> Assets/Scripts/CraftItem.cs(11,6): error CS0136: A local variable
>   named `requiredcount' cannot be declared in this scope because it
>   would give a different meaning to`requiredcount', which is already
>   used in a `parent or current' scope to denote something else

I can't find any good answers online and don't know how to fix it, heres the script:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;



    public class CraftItem : MonoBehaviour {

         public GameObject countholder;

         public void Craftitem(int crafttype, int requiredtype, int requiredcount, int requiredamount){
             requiredcount = countholder.GetComponent<Counts> ().Counters [requiredtype];
                 if(requiredcount => requiredamount){

             }

         }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `=>` in the `if` condition which in C# means arrow function / lambda expression. The operator you are looking for is `>=`